# Mysql count group by and left join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

Below is a simple query for a click tracker.  I've had a look at a lot of other posts and I'm scratching my head.  I cannot get this query to work so that all rows from the calendar table (one calendar day per row) are displayed:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calendar_date, '%a %D') AS calendar_date, 
count( tracker_id ) as clicks
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN offer_tracker USING(calendar_id)
WHERE 
  calendar_month = Month(CURDATE()) AND 
  calendar_year = Year(CURDATE()) AND ( offer_id = 4 OR offer_id IS NULL )
GROUP BY calendar_date;
```

It's nearly there but not all rows in the calendar table are returned i.e. there is no Fri 2nd, Tue 6th, Wed 7th etc:

[image: result set]

Does anyone have any ideas on where I'm going wrong?  Should I be using a subquery?

Comment: Could be the LEFT JOIN in case some rows have NULL values in calendar_id

Comment: Hello medopal, calendar_id in the offer_tracker table is set to NOT NULL and I can't find any rows with null in calendar_id but thanks for flagging it as a suggestion.

Comment: The query is correct. Mysql not able to return results when there is no place to refer to `Fri 2nd`. An example solution will be like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386530/return-multiple-copies-slightly-modified/7387014#7387014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the `offer_id` is from the `offer_tracker` table. When you have an (left) outer join, and you use a field from the right table in a `WHERE` condition (like your `offer_id = 4`), the join is actually cancelled and gives same results as an inner join.

The attempt to lift the cancellation (`offer_id = 4 OR offer_id IS NULL`) does not work as you expect. Any row from `offer_tracker` with `offer_id <> 4` has already passed the LEFT JOIN but is removed because of the WHERE condition. So, no row with `Friday 2nd` will appear in the results if there is a row with `offer_id` different than `4` for this date.

---

Move the `offer_id = 4` check to the `LEFT JOIN`, instead:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calendar_date, '%a %D') AS calendar_date
     , count( tracker_id ) as clicks
FROM calendar
  LEFT JOIN offer_tracker 
    ON  offer_tracker.calendar_id = calendar.calendar_id
    AND offer_id = 4
WHERE calendar_month = Month(CURDATE())
  AND calendar_year = Year(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY calendar_date
```

Comment: ypercube, you're a genius.  Thank you for your help and comprehensive answer.